# How to create a website where you can post (anonymous or with nick name) only post and read others posts?

Tags: web, social-networking

I just want to know what languages and technologies to use to store anonymous people posts with their nick name.
I want to make something like this:
www.ispovesti.com

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

What kind of question is this? There are dozens of languages and technologies which can be used for this. Either the standard php & mysql combination... Using Ajax for the modern GUI design and usability... Or alternatives like mongodb, asp, whatever you want, or can use?

Another advice - keep your hands off anonym sites - if something happens, or some sick sh*t get's posted - you'll be the one in court.